# Why do equipped items keep disappearing from my follower?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am using Kharjo and every time I put a weapon on him it disappears! I tried enchanting the weapon and naming it, and even dropping it and making him pick it up and it still keeps happening. So far it has only occurred with Daedra weapons that i am aware of - I am still testing the issue.

What is causing this? Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. What platform? PC, XBox or PS3?

Comment: Maybe he's getting disarmed by Draugr, or maybe he's selling them on the sly.

Comment: Could be similar to the known bug with followers and bows where they will never equip a bow you give them. If your 'weapon' is a bow. There is a mod to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

Disappearing in what sense?

If you give your follower a weapon which has lower stats than what they have already it will not be equipped and will remain in their inventory.

However if you mean the weapon they take disappears completely from their inventory then it could possibly be a bug with Skyrim or the item in question is a Quest item and cannot be taken by a follower.

Comment: If the item is a Quest item then it won't come out of your inventory in the first place. You also get a message saying it can't be removed, so I reckon it would be pretty hard to think that  you've given it to your follower.

Answer (score 3):

I think the follower drops the item - it doesn't disappear. My follower just dropped his weapon (with very specific stats). I thought I had found a new identical weapon but it had been "moved" from my follower to the ground somehow. I just fought an NPC that used shouts - maybe the Disarm shout made the follower drop his weapon.

In case of potions atl the follower may have used the item(s).